# FABRIC MC / FABRIC API. Client: How to get player name? It's just a solution

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I have tried to find answer in internet - I can't) But reverse engineering helps me.

That method will help you:

```
var username = MinecraftClient.getInstance().getSession().getUsername();
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not meet the quality requirements as a question here. You will greatly improve your experiences here if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. Please read  [ask] and [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method will help you:

```
var username = MinecraftClient.getInstance().getSession().getUsername();
```

Comment: There has not been a question asked yet, so you can't answer it. In order to post a question you intend to answer yourself, you must first write a question that meets this site's quality guidelines, which you have not yet done.